# Performance efficient way to check a string in a Set

Tags: java, performance, spring, spring-mvc, dictionary

I have following
supportedLocales :
   en_US
   en_IN
   fr_FR

In my code, I am using it as Set of "MyCustomLocale" class.

I want to know whats the best efficient way to check if this **Set** contains String like "en_US"

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Set or a Map? The title doesn't match the description.

Comment: @Steve : Its a Set. Edited Question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about performance; this almost certainly isn't going to be your bottleneck, and it's not worth making your code complicated for little or no benefit. Just use `map.containsKey("en_US");`--or let Spring resolve the locales for you.

Comment: The problem is it is Set<MyCustomLocale> , and I want to check if en_US is in there or not. And since it will be checked for every Spring:message code tag, thats the reason I am caring about performance.

Comment: @NoviceUser Then why did you say `Map`? You really *ought* to be using a `Map` if you're trying to look it up by a key like this.

Comment: As its pair of values which is to be supported on my site. They do not belong to a key-value pair